# Get only 1 row with MAX() in colums - SAP HANA

Tags: sql, greatest-n-per-group, hana

I've this table:

```
|--------------|-------------|-----------|-----------|
|    cli_id    |    email    |   is_one  |  n_order  |
|--------------|-------------|-----------|-----------|
|       1      |   a@a.com   |     1     |   2341    |
|--------------|-------------|-----------|-----------|
|       1      |   b@a.com   |     0     |     21    |
|--------------|-------------|-----------|-----------|
|       1      |   c@a.com   |     0     |    121    |
|--------------|-------------|-----------|-----------|
|       1      |   a@a.com   |     1     |     50    |
|--------------|-------------|-----------|-----------|
```

How can I select only 1 email, the one with MAX(is_one) and MAX(n_order)?   For example, I cannot use "WHERE is_one = 1", I must use "max(is_one)" or equivalent.

The result must be this one:

```
|-------------|
|    email    |
|-------------|
|   a@a.com   |
|-------------|
```

Thanks!

Comment: what should happen if I add a new row, containing is_one = 0 and n_order = 3000? The answers of forpas and Godron Linoff give different results in this case

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm . . .

```
select top (1) email
from t
order by is_one desc, n_order desc;
```

Comment: I cannot use "order by" inside subquery

Comment: @NicolauRoca . . . Of course you can.  But pretty much only when you specify `TOP`.

Answer (score 1):

You want the `email` from the row that contains: 
the maximum value of `is_one` and 
the maximum value of `n_order`, right?

```
select email from tablename
where
  is_one = (select max(is_one) from tablename)
  and
  n_order = (select max(n_order) from tablename)
```

Comment: I cannot use this because it could be a casuistic when "is_one" and "n_order" have more than 1 result for this "max" value

Comment: `max()` returns only 1 result.

Comment: If there are more than 1 emails with these max values then you must clarify if you want all of them or 1 and which 1.

Answer (score 0):

use r`ow_number()` if it supported

```
   select * from (
  select *, row_number()over(order by  is_one desc,n_order desc) rn
   ) a where a.rn=1
```

Comment: I cannot use "order by" inside subquery

Comment: @NicolauRoca that is window function

Answer (score 0):

You can use a subquery with `max` aggregate function as below

```
SELECT t~email
  FROM tab AS t
 WHERE (t~is_one, t~n_order) IN
      ( SELECT max(t~is_one), max(t~n_order)
          FROM tab )
```